# Create and include separated file in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
var lang = this.props.lang;
    var language = "";
    switch (lang){
        case 1 :
            language = require('../../common/languages/en');
            break;
        case 2 :
            language = require('../../common/languages/fr');
            break;
        case 3 :
            language = require('../../common/languages/de');
            break;
        default:
            language = require('../../common/languages/nl');
    }
```

which I reuse in many other components.

How can I put this code in one separated file and then use it in my components?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to set the language globally, just put it in the Context at your root component:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

If you want to have different languages in different components, a better idea would be to make a mixin:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins[2](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins)